# How can I make my webserver running on android publically available

Tags: android, webserver

i have created a web server in android it works fine but the problem is it is not publicly available it says:

```
The server at ip:port is taking too long to respond.
```

when I type device ip:port but when I connect to it with tethering it  with my computer I can only see it so how can I make it publicly available...

Comment: I don't understand the question here (sorry)... Are you saying you can only access it when you connect directly?

Comment: this is what i want. start my webserver ,enable data connect...,get the ip of device using adb shell netcfg and type the addr:port and it should display the page. is it possible??

Comment: You probably won't be able to, as mobile ISPs usually block incoming connections (through use of a NAT, perhaps?)

Comment: how can i use nat

Comment: Using NAT won't help you; it's what (I'm conjecturing) mobile ISPs use to prevent incoming connections

Comment: so there is no way, then tell me how ksweb is publically available

Comment: That would work using your device over WIFI and configuring your router's NAT to dorward TCP80 port to your device. Through mobile networks, most addresses are indeed NAT'ed which breaks the possibility to host servers in them. KSWEB seems made for local debugging and developpement, not production.

Comment: i want that only

Comment: Do not cross-post, please: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/52335/how-to-make-my-android-ip-publicaly-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try Pagekite (https://pagekite.net/). Open Source, free, and ported to Android. This program was designed for your uses. This program can make any android web server (as well as any on PC or MAC) accessible from the internet, from behind a Nat / Firewall / ISP. Pagekite sets up everything for you - tunnels, DNS, port forwarding, etc. There is a lot of documentation on this small program, take a look at it. (http://pagekite.net/wiki/)

Comment: do u know any technique to get this done with progrmaming

Comment: Pagekit is open source, written in python, you can easily create something in java. If this is not an option what pagekite basically does is creates SSH tunnels to a public servers. I know of several Java and Mono libraries for SSH that should be portable to Android. (i.e http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqWwbgyS990, this guy was  using no-ip url to do this, i want to ask that i have registerd a url on no-ip no to which ip i have forward the connections

Answer (score 3):

@tapped-out is right.  I'd be surprised if a mobile ISP allows incoming TCP/IP connections to your phone.

Here's what you can do though:

- If you are usually on a given wireless network and you can configure the port forwarding, you ought to be able to tell the router to give your phone a reserved IP and forward the ports to it.  People can then get to your phone's website through your landline ISP if your phone is connected via Wifi.  Use a dynamic IP service such as No-IP if you need a free external DNS name.
- You could install OpenVPN on a publicly accessible machine and then configure OpenVPN on your phone (it's installable via Google Play) to connect to this server (and configure it using `ccd` to use a "static" VPN IP).  I believe if you configure forwarding properly your phone's port 80, etc. could be accessible, but it might be slightly easier to install apache on this publicly accessible server and reverse proxy to your phone's VPN address.
- If your phone is rooted (though there may be an app to do this without root or a Debian chroot), you could look into running tor and setting up a hidden service.  Even if you don't care about the security aspects of Tor it's useful for this situation - edit: forgot to mention that you'd need to tell others to use an onion web proxy like [tor2web](http://tor2web.org/) or similar to access without tor installed.